# Flume sinks data in inconsistance fashion

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I have got a problem. I am using apache flume to read the logs from txt file to sink to hdfs. somehow some records are getting skipped while reading. I am using fileChannel please check the below configuration.

```
agent2.sources = file_server
agent2.sources.file_server.type=exec
agent2.sources.file_server.command = tail -F /home/datafile/error.log
agent2.sources.file_server.channels = fileChannel


agent2.channels = fileChannel
agent2.channels.fileChannel.type=file
agent2.channels.fileChannel.capacity = 12000
agent2.channels.fileChannel.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent2.channels.fileChannel.checkpointDir=/home/data/flume/checkpoint
agent2.channels.fileChannel.dataDirs=/home/data/flume/data


# Agent2 sinks
agent2.sinks = hadooper loged
agent2.sinks.hadooper.type = hdfs
agent2.sinks.loged.type=logger
agent2.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/flume/data/file
agent2.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent1.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent2.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent2.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.rollInterval = 600
agent2.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent2.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.rollSize = 67108864
agent2.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.batchSize = 10
agent2.sinks.hadooper.hdfs.idleTimeout=0
agent2.sinks.hadooper.channel = fileChannel
agent2.sinks.loged.channel = fileChannel
agent2.sinks.hdfs.threadsPoolSize = 20
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your are using 2 sinks reading both of them from a single channel; in that case, a Flume event read by one of the 2 sinks is not read by the other one, and viceversa.

If you want both sinks receive a copy of the same Flume event, then you will need to create a dedicated channel for each sink. Once created these channels, the default channel selector, which is `ReplicatingChannelSelector`, will create a copy into each channel.

Comment: Thanks frb for your reply... but it's solved ... 2 sinks can read from same channel.

Comment: Yes, they can read from the same channel, that's for sure, but are you sure the sinks are reading the same events? I don't think so. If your channel has, let's say the folowing events: ABCDEF, then if the first sink take A, then the second sink will take B, and not A.